# Procedimiento almacenado sin cursor

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

En un procedimiento almacenado en oracle tengo una consulta y quiero recorrer la tabla resultante para mostrar los datos, pero la condición es que debo hacerlo sin usar cursores. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto? esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure EmpleadosCargo(parSucId in sucursal.sucid%type)
is
 varNombre empleado.empnombrecompleto%type;
 varCargo cargo.carnombre%type;

begin
    SELECT emp.empnombrecompleto, ca.carnombre
    into varNombre,varCargo
    FROM EMPLEADO emp
    JOIN cargoxubicacion cu
    on emp.carid = cu.carid and
    emp.sucid=cu.sucid
    JOIN Cargo ca
    on ca.carid= cu.carid
    where parSucId = emp.sucid;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un `for`/`select`, que iterará por los registros que devuelva tu consulta.

Es más fácil verlo en código, sería algo como:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure EmpleadosCargo(parSucId in sucursal.sucid%type)
is
 varNombre empleado.empnombrecompleto%type;
 varCargo cargo.carnombre%type;

begin
    for loop_var in (
      select emp.empnombrecompleto, ca.carnombre
        from EMPLEADO emp
             inner join cargoxubicacion cu on emp.carid = cu.carid and emp.sucid=cu.sucid
             inner join Cargo ca on ca.carid = cu.carid
        where parSucId = emp.sucid
    ) loop
      dbms_output.put_line('nombre: '||loop_var.empnombrecompleto);
      dbms_output.put_line('cargo: '||loop_var.carnombre);
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Excelente! muchas gracias por la ayuda